SQL Server RML Utilities - installation on Windows Server 2022
Trying to run the RML Utilities on Windows Server 2022 & this is listed as compatible but when I run readtrace getting error 0x80040154 & the connection to the db server fails, which seems to be due to I haven't installed the extra componenents required - doh. However when I download and try and install the SQL Server native client it won't install and says it is not compatible with this OS.
Has anyone else encountered this problem & knows a way past it ?

alternatively does anybody know a way to make the RML utilities use the ODBC or OLEDB drivers when making a connection

The RML cmd prompt OStress parameter -D will allow you to use a DSN
